# Linq SQL GroupJoin Error

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Here is my code display an error like

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0411  The type arguments for method `Queryable.GroupJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(IQueryable<TOuter>, IEnumerable<TInner>, Expression<Func<TOuter, TKey>>, Expression<Func<TInner, TKey>>, Expression<Func<TOuter, IEnumerable<TInner>, TResult>>)` cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

```
data.RawMaterail.Where(c => c.Category.categoryType == 1)
                .Join(data.Sizes, x => x.DiamondSize.diamondSizeId, 
                                  y => y.DiamondSize.diamondSizeId, 
                                  (x, y) => new { RM = x, Size = y })
                .GroupJoin(data.PriceLevels.Where(c => c.priceLevelId == PriceLevelId), 
                           x => new { x.RM.rMId , x.Size.sizeId}, 
                           y => new { y.rmId , y.sizeId}, 
                           (y, x) => new { Category = y, PurityLevel = x })
                .SelectMany(xy => xy.PurityLevel.DefaultIfEmpty(), 
                           (x, y) => new { Category = x.Category, PurityLevel = y })
                .Select(item => new
                 {
                     Code = item.Category.RM.rMCode + " " + item.Category.Size.sizeName,
                     Name = item.Category.RM.rMName + " " + item.Category.Size.sizeName,
                     Date = item.PurityLevel.rowDate,
                     Id = (int)item.Category.RM.rMId,
                     RateId = (int?)item.PurityLevel.stonePriceLevelId ?? 0,
                     Price = (double?)item.PurityLevel.price ?? 0,
                     PriceLevelId = (int?)item.PurityLevel.priceLevelId ?? 0,
                     TypeId = (int)item.Category.Size.sizeId,
                     IsRateChanged = false
                 }).OrderBy(c => c.Date).ThenBy(n => n.TypeId).ToList();
```

The error display based on GroupJoin position and how can join this type of Left Join

Comment: IMHO _join_ & _group join_ in LINQ are always easy to write and understand in query syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data.RawMaterail.Where(c => c.Category.categoryType == 1)
                .Join(data.Sizes, x => x.DiamondSize.diamondSizeId, 
                                  y => y.DiamondSize.diamondSizeId, 
                                  (x, y) => new { RM = x, Size = y })
                .GroupJoin(data.PriceLevels.Where(c => c.priceLevelId == PriceLevelId), 
                           x => new { RID = (int?)x.RM.rMId , SID = (int?)x.Size.sizeId}, 
                           y => new { RID = (int?)y.rmId , SID = (int?)y.sizeId}, 
                           (y, x) => new { Category = y, PurityLevel = x })
                .SelectMany(xy => xy.PurityLevel.DefaultIfEmpty(), 
                           (x, y) => new { Category = x.Category, PurityLevel = y })
                .Select(item => new
                 {
                     Code = item.Category.RM.rMCode + " " + item.Category.Size.sizeName,
                     Name = item.Category.RM.rMName + " " + item.Category.Size.sizeName,
                     Date = item.PurityLevel.rowDate,
                     Id = (int)item.Category.RM.rMId,
                     RateId = (int?)item.PurityLevel.stonePriceLevelId ?? 0,
                     Price = (double?)item.PurityLevel.price ?? 0,
                     PriceLevelId = (int?)item.PurityLevel.priceLevelId ?? 0,
                     TypeId = (int)item.Category.Size.sizeId,
                     IsRateChanged = false
                 }).OrderBy(c => c.Date).ThenBy(n => n.TypeId).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the key selectors to

```
x => new { x.RM.rMId , x.Size.sizeId}, 
y => new { y.rmId , y.sizeId},
```

to

```
x => new { RMId = x.RM.rMId , SizeId = x.Size.sizeId}, 
y => new { RMId = y.rmId, SizeId = y.sizeId},
```

One of the properties was named `rMId` and the other `rmId` (the case of `m` is different). So the compiler generates **two different anonymous types**. But `TKey` needs to be **the same type** for the outer and the inner key selector.

By declaring the property names of the anonymous type explicitly you avoid this error and the compiler uses the same anonymous type for both key selectors.